# Pre load images from an ajax request before displaying them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to load html content which contains images, the problem is that i don't want the effect of blinking on images due to loading, to achieve that i need to pre load images inside the response body before inserting it to guarantee a smooth update.

Current Code:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'hello.php',
method: 'GET',
data:'id='+id,
success: function(data) {
$('#section').html(data);               
}
});
```

Any Solutions?

Thanks

Comment: did you give my answer a try?

Answer (score 0):

I use the the jQuery [onImagesLoad plugin](http://www.cirkuit.net/projects/jquery/onImagesLoad/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this <del>(untested)</del>:

```
var imagesLoading = 0;

$.ajax({
    url: 'hello.php',
    method: 'GET',
    data: 'id=' + id,
    success: function(data) {
        imagesLoading = 0;

        $(data).filter('img').each(function() {
            imagesLoading++;

            var image = new Image();

            image.onload = function() {
                imagesLoading--;
                if(imagesLoading == 0) {
                    $('#section').html(data);
                }
            };

            image.src = $(this).attr('src');
        });
    }
});
```

Works fine when I tried it.

Comment: How so?  Not seeing anything?  Images loading on screen?